# PrimeNG select hours with the slider

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to edit the [PrimeNG slider](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/slider) in such a way that I can select a time period.

When the user opens the application the slider should be set at 12:00. But then the user can expand the selection all the way from 00:00 tot 23:59.

But I can't find anything in the documentation about changing the values from the slider. It's just set from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 0 as the minValue and 2359 as the maxValue. Then a custom format based on the rangeValues

Comment: Hm a silly thing we might have missed is that now a time like 0990 can be selected. Or 1080. So that's not an option.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can use anything but numbers for the slider.  `min` and `max` are both numbers

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a few years late, but I was looking for ways to do this and came up with this...

You need to convert a decimal number to time. There's a number of good online calculators that do this. [This one](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php) happens to also show the equations to do so. Just be sure to set the unit time to minutes (or change to whatever you need to use...)

For Midnight to Midnight, you'll want `min=0` and `max=1440`. 1440 is simply 60 * 24 (minutes in a day). You can adjust this as is needed.

However, this means that now your slider only displays 0-1440, which is not what you want. You need to plug the number into a function that prints out a string that's formatted to the time.

```
convertDecimalToTime(decimal: number) {
    let running, hours, minutes;

    running = decimal / 60;
    hours = Math.floor(running);
    running = running - hours;
    minutes = Math.round(running * 60);
    
    return hours + ':' + minutes;
}
```

You should now have a slider that outputs a time.